# Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'empty'

Tags: jquery

I'm so confuse with this. I'm using jquery 1.9.1 to append a div's inner html to another div. But when trying to debug with chrome developer tools, it gave me this error inside jquery library.

my Html:

```
<body>
    <s:form action="/save" method="POST">
        <div class="educationForm">
            <div class="educations">
                <label>Position</label>
                <input type="text" name="educations[0].index" value="1" />
                <br/>
                <label>School</label>
                <input type="text" name="educations[0].school" />
                <br/>
                <label>Degree</label>
                <input type="text" name="educations[0].degree" />
                <br/>
                <label>GPA</label>
                <input type="text" name="educations[0].scored" />
                <br/>
                <label>Start Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="educations[0].startDate" />
                <br/>
                <label>End Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="educations[0].endDate" />
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>  <a href="#" id="addButton">Add new Edu</a>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </s:form>
    <div class="template_educations" style="display:none">
        <div class="educations">
            <label>Position</label>
            <input type="text" name="educations[_X_].index" />
            <br/>
            <label>School</label>
            <input type="text" name="educations[_X_].school" />
            <br/>
            <label>Degree</label>
            <input type="text" name="educations[_X_].degree" />
            <br/>
            <label>GPA</label>
            <input type="text" name="educations[_X_].scored" />
            <br/>
            <label>Start Date</label>
            <input type="text" name="educations[_X_].startDate" />
            <br/>
            <label>End Date</label>
            <input type="text" name="educations[_X_].endDate" />
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addButton").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".educationForm").append($(".template_educations").html);
        $(".educationForm").children(".educations").last().children("input").each(function(){           
            var count = $(".educationForm").children(".education").length();
            var value = $(this).attr("name");
            value.replace("_X_", count + 1);
            $(this).attr("name", value);
        });         
    });
});
```

Please help me determine whether this is a bug in jquery library or there's something wrong with my code, since i didn't use any function `empty` inside my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be `html()`..instead of `html`..

```
....
$(".educationForm").append($(".template_educations").html());
....                                                 //--^^---here
```

Comment: Yup.  Remember that it's a method call.

Comment: no i mean the downvoters... :)...not you...i am sure it wasn't you ...thanks anyways... happy coding... glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

use this line

```
 $(".educationForm").append($(".template_educations").html);
```

as like

```
    $(".educationForm").append($(".template_educations").html());
```